# Excess thin line under div with background image

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have div with next styles:

```
.top-pattern {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 92px;
  background-image: url("https://s21.postimg.org/p0amqt8wn/pattern-top-big.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

It is pretty simple and works great. But at some devices (mac and mobile) there is weird line appeared under the div. What is this? How to remove it?

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/wx92fb61/

Screenshot: https://gyazo.com/3020d6720d27fcbd0315a55fce0fb016

P.S. I checked my image hundred times: there is NO line in the image.

Answer (score 0):

you css must be like, for example :

```
@media (min-width:768px;){
.top-pattern {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 94px;
  background-image: url("https://s21.postimg.org/p0amqt8wn/pattern-top-big.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: contain;
}
}

@media (max-width:768px;){
.top-pattern {
  width: 100%;
  height: 94px;
  background-image: url("https://s21.postimg.org/p0amqt8wn/pattern-top-big.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: contain;
}
}
```

in phones or tablets you better have a width of 100% than a pixel value, then you should add a initial scale in the head part of your html to catch a fixed value for the devices.

Comment: It doesn't fix a bug, I still see this line on my mac.

Comment: add a screen shot for the line

Comment: change your height into     height: 94px; and it should work ;)

Comment: Line moves 2px down =).

Answer (score 0):

See, if you can override this CSS class and remove box-shadow.
I think this is what is getting you that border.

```
.image-box-component .image-viewer {
     box-shadow: 0 0 0px rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried to add this css to my div, but nothing changed.